# Dig faster than speed of light, Possible?

Tags: packet, dig

I personally love to `dig` sites that I know. .Here's a wierd thing I saw up on my terminal after running `dig www-contestwinners.com`:-

```
; <<>> DiG 9.9.5-3ubuntu0.1-Ubuntu <<>> www-contestwinners.com
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 27237
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 4096
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;www-contestwinners.com.        IN  A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
www-contestwinners.com. 300 IN  A   8.29.143.192

;; Query time: 40 msec
;; SERVER: 127.0.1.1#53(127.0.1.1)
;; WHEN: Sun Jun 06 20:31:40 IST 2015
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 67
```

Which is absurd as my ISP is about 200kms away and I'm on a DSL connection. Considering the packets travel at speed of light, which makes the time to reach the packet from my device to the ISP server about 0.6 ms which is not much but the site's server is in US which is at a distance of 13000 km from my ISP which makes the time to reach the server about 43 ms. So, the total round trip takes about (43+0.6)x2= 87.2 ms.

I'm totally confused/excited. I think I just broke a basic law of Physics :p

**EDIT:** I checked `dig www-contestwinners.com +trace` to check against caching and got:-

```
;; global options: +cmd
.           412410  IN  NS  i.root-servers.net.
.           412410  IN  NS  k.root-servers.net.
.           412410  IN  NS  f.root-servers.net.
.           412410  IN  NS  g.root-servers.net.
.           412410  IN  NS  e.root-servers.net.
.           412410  IN  NS  l.root-servers.net.
.           412410  IN  NS  h.root-servers.net.
.           412410  IN  NS  b.root-servers.net.
.           412410  IN  NS  a.root-servers.net.
.           412410  IN  NS  m.root-servers.net.
.           412410  IN  NS  j.root-servers.net.
.           412410  IN  NS  c.root-servers.net.
.           412410  IN  NS  d.root-servers.net.
.           518400  IN  RRSIG   NS 8 0 518400 20150618050000 20150608040000 48613 . TJF2HD0Ob5niqlCZNhlOYHvwlZmEpebgV8uFwgvRLBCQb22sq+S8Hr4d CX9S5WgzRlTxCSQ3Bi9TJNlyf221rE1K53kFbRae6/vzjR2MukvF5d8G SEWinOcJ9n7l6fTq/HoxCv/GfliY6gTPWxrc8uiABdYYOj3u3XoUmbF7 Cug=
;; Received 397 bytes from 127.0.1.1#53(127.0.1.1) in 5306 ms

com.            172800  IN  NS  a.gtld-servers.net.
com.            172800  IN  NS  b.gtld-servers.net.
com.            172800  IN  NS  c.gtld-servers.net.
com.            172800  IN  NS  d.gtld-servers.net.
com.            172800  IN  NS  e.gtld-servers.net.
com.            172800  IN  NS  f.gtld-servers.net.
com.            172800  IN  NS  g.gtld-servers.net.
com.            172800  IN  NS  h.gtld-servers.net.
com.            172800  IN  NS  i.gtld-servers.net.
com.            172800  IN  NS  j.gtld-servers.net.
com.            172800  IN  NS  k.gtld-servers.net.
com.            172800  IN  NS  l.gtld-servers.net.
com.            172800  IN  NS  m.gtld-servers.net.
com.            86400   IN  DS  30909 8 2 E2D3C916F6DEEAC73294E8268FB5885044A833FC5459588F4A9184CF C41A5766
com.            86400   IN  RRSIG   DS 8 1 86400 20150618050000 20150608040000 48613 . kSsNvyvdzfiJAxfpaRq4+bAe2JuKcDTcRnHDgGhiHNRsbcg04fHv/TNt Kkl0LuBpLcBWhBr74OkCLJxx5Q1KFkRhum2R7gHj6h5u8s4J84feqWeu fx69Defg2NWhToWDnqz0WzlUKF0nDsEyXTJDjsUeFrXu+baR3NSMLxvb zdU=
;; Received 746 bytes from 192.203.230.10#53(e.root-servers.net) in 5221 ms

www-contestwinners.com. 172800  IN  NS  dan.ns.cloudflare.com.
www-contestwinners.com. 172800  IN  NS  anna.ns.cloudflare.com.
CK0POJMG874LJREF7EFN8430QVIT8BSM.com. 86400 IN NSEC3 1 1 0 - CK0QFMDQRCSRU0651QLVA1JQB21IF7UR NS SOA RRSIG DNSKEY NSEC3PARAM
CK0POJMG874LJREF7EFN8430QVIT8BSM.com. 86400 IN RRSIG NSEC3 8 2 86400 20150613045314 20150606034314 33878 com. syTPVIWKgitzBOsgVgzOl7nEIsu7jhsmSXPzzLuGVUwZZC1QHc4dxmKP MkZUR+VcaY657/Knjk7Il5oOKWo8ZlTatk3+34504gWwdnbB3BShqTKS CFsWOEdw5wyf0gumuQk5GKnVR5Noo+q2+ZOxxy7LkEl0F/h7fuYj7sJA VkM=
A7FUA6LKSQCDHL6JDO7SFU649KJ6FAU5.com. 86400 IN NSEC3 1 1 0 - A7G276R35K72HBA9TE7NSAOEFTS5CADU NS DS RRSIG
A7FUA6LKSQCDHL6JDO7SFU649KJ6FAU5.com. 86400 IN RRSIG NSEC3 8 2 86400 20150614050705 20150607035705 33878 com. lIZrvjQdR4oNJTo8gW1uuzs1IuFXiqwZbI757xxBRdrYl22IDSDM4U4G i8PNVSOQ2T3ub++0VhoioWnp3aD+Uc1XmdR/jI5Z5bosIsfIrCj+CSCm ZlDShTEDsfOBLxvZ2LByGwibTHi/yuH57O+Zx3zp21RZu3xLAn2WT2aZ TrE=
;; Received 675 bytes from 192.12.94.30#53(e.gtld-servers.net) in 1539 ms

www-contestwinners.com. 300 IN  A   8.29.143.192
;; Received 67 bytes from 173.245.59.108#53(dan.ns.cloudflare.com) in 53 ms
```

How is this possible?

Comment: What about some transparent cache DNS?

Comment: I don't think my ISP uses transparent DNS cache @RomeoNinov

Comment: Looks like your machine is caching it: SERVER: 127.0.1.1#53(127.0.1.1)

Comment: `;; SERVER: 127.0.1.1#53(127.0.1.1)` - your local server has cached the answer.

Comment: As far as I know, I don't think that the last section of `dig` has anything to do with caching.

Comment: The last section tells you what server provided the answer, here it's the loopback.

Comment: Added `dig www-contestwinners.com +trace` to question. Still, just about the same query time. @user1794469

Comment: A similar question was asked [on SuperUser](http://superuser.com/questions/921221/ping-faster-than-light) and received an incredible amount of upvotes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The name server you queried isn't in the US. It's much closer to you. (So, unfortunately, your Nobel will have to wait.)

That trace output shows www-contestwinners.com is using CloudFlare for its DNS provider. [CloudFlare](https://www.cloudflare.com/) operates numerous servers around the world and your query gets directed to the closest (or as best they can manage) server.

(Note that the name server need not be—and often isn't—anywhere near the web server. Often name servers aren't even handled by the same company.)